# How to fix git bash error Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: git, git-bash

I am not able to open git bash on windows. When I try to open git bash by right click on git local repo directory then it just creating the file **mintty.exe.stackdump** and not opening the git bash window. But if I open **Git GUI here** it is working fine.

**mintty.exe.stackdump** file contains below information

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=000FFFFC39F
rax=00000000FFFFC39F rbx=00000000007766B0 rcx=00000000007766BC
rdx=0000000000776828 rsi=0000000000777024 rdi=00000000FFFFC39F
r8 =0000000000000004 r9 =0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000246 r12=0000000000000001 r13=00000000FFFFC3DC
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
rbp=0000000000000001 rsp=00000000FFFFC188
program=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe, pid 23484, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
```

So please help me to understand what is this issue? and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling? Mintty is part of the cygwin terminal emulator. If it is fried a fresh installation might do the trick just fine.

Comment: I want to know the reason why is it stopped working? till yesterday it was working fine. I don't have permissions to re install. is there any alternate to solve this issue?

Comment: So what have you changed configurationwise in the meantime?

Comment: I didn't change anything

Comment: Are you running git under a custom command prompt such as cmder or conemu?

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue today. Probably way too late for you, but this was caused by some issue with the configuration file (.minttyrc in your home directory).

I saved a backup removed it, and it now works.

Adding it here as it may help someone else in the future.

See the following link for more info: [Git Bash - STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374053/git-bash-status-access-violation)

Comment: Great find! I recently changed several of the window's properties (App Icon -> Options...) and after a reboot, Git Bash would not open. I found `.minttyrc` in the home directory and, after removing the line `StatusLine=yes`, Git Bash opened (and just to confirm, re-added that line and Git Bash would no longer open).

Comment: Glad it was helpful. My experience was similar in that it seems that some settings in the configuration file make the application "crash", which is unfortunate.

Answer (score -2):

Go to control panel > add or remove program > uninstall git

Then install it

Comment: I don't think this helps the poster to understand the issue.

Comment: Can you explain **why** one should do that?