# Git Bash - STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: git, git-bash

I have installed GIT, when trying to open GIT bash , getting below dump

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=7FFA4DDBC20C
rax=00003C3E97CF8846 rbx=0000000000000013 rcx=00000000FFE00000
rdx=0000000000004000 rsi=00000000FFFFC370 rdi=000000010047AB16
r8 =00000000FFFFC201 r9 =0000000000000001 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000246 r12=0000000600043640 r13=00000000FFFFC5C0
r14=0000000100496220 r15=000000000000000F
rbp=00000000FFFFC520 rsp=00000000FFFFC250
program=D:\software\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe, pid 11520, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFC520  7FFA4DDBC20C (00000000104, 00000000000, 00000000000, 000FFFFC000)
000FFFFC520  7FFA4DD9A9CD (0010047AB16, 0010047AB16, 00000000013, 6F646E69575C3A43)
000FFFFC520  0010041DCA6 (00080000000, 00080000000, 00080000000, 00080000000)
000FFFFC520  0010043F856 (00180190B4C, 0000000000E, 00180057A40, 0000000000E)
000FFFFCCD0  00180047F24 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  00180045A03 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  00180045AB4 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
```

tried uninstall and then installing, but same issue

Any suggestions

Comment: Check if the following answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/34307471/4901118

Comment: reinstallment can resolve the most problems. https://gitforwindows.org/

Comment: I have the same issue as well. For me the issue started after upgrading to version 2.27 from 2.24. Please let me know if you found any support. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 4):

Might be a bit late, but I run into the same issue today.
I was able to solve it by removing the `.minttyrc` file in the user folder `C:/Users/YourName/.minttyrc`.

I tried to increase the width of the terminal window and ended up with a crazy number of columns:

```
Columns=100000000
Rows=58
ScrollbackLines=1874919424
```

Answer (score 0):

The default column size is too big.

I can resolve the issue by decreasing the column size:

Edit this file:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\.minttyrc
```

Edit columns from:

```
Columns=80000
```

To smaller size (120 is default windows 10 command prompt column size):

```
Columns=120
```